# python détect if file is tar or tar.gz or zip

Tags: python, compression, tar

i have a problem, i need to identify file type (tar, tar.gz or zip) i found a solution in this site :
[Python - mechanism to identify compressed file type and uncompress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044562/python-mechanism-to-identify-compressed-file-type-and-uncompress)

but the solution not work for tar file, because tar file have not same start caractere...

```
magic_dict = {
    "\x1f\x8b\x08": "gz",
    "\x00\x00\x00": "tar",
    "\x50\x4b\x03\x04": "zip"
    }

max_len = max(len(x) for x in magic_dict)

def file_type(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        file_start = f.read(max_len)
    for magic, filetype in magic_dict.items():
        if file_start.startswith(magic):
            return filetype
    return "no match"
```

How can i make detect tar file ?

Comment: Is this python 2 or python 3?

Comment: i use python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

At least GNU tar **has** a "magic signature", but it is not at offset 0 (the beginning of file), but at offset 257, and it is the string `ustar` followed by NUL character; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)#UStar_format